# Syntax error near unexpected elif near line 23 shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell script, the error occurs in line 23 which is 
    elif [`grep $uni Aus-Uni.txt | wc -l` -ne 0 ]
can anyone please tell me why i get this error

```
"2") echo "please enter an number to view universities or a state name to view the number of uni in that state"
read uni
if [ uni -le `cat Aus-Uni.txt | wc -l` ]
then
echo `tail -$uni Aus-Uni.txt`
else
echo "The number you entered is too large"
fi
elif [`grep $uni Aus-Uni.txt | wc -l` -ne 0 ]
then
echo `grep $uni Aus-Uni.txt`
else
echo "No university in $uni was found"
fi
;;
```

Comment: `fi`? do you mean `if`?

Comment: Remove the ```fi``` before ```elif [`grep $uni Aus-Uni.txt | wc -l` -ne 0 ]```

Comment: i use 2 if statement there and i think i should end the if statements with fi

Comment: i tried delete fi before elif but it still shows the same error

Comment: Paste your code into http://www.shellcheck.net/ and let it help find the errors. For example, you need a space between `[` and the backtick

Answer (score 1):

Bash is telling you that it's not expecting an `elif` there - and for the code you've posted, neither do I.

`elif` is an abbreviation of `else if` and it needs to go where an else clause could be.

If you indent your code, this is easier to see.

Here I've changed your `elif` to an `if` which bash will find more structurally correct.  However, it's not clear (to me) what you're trying to achieve, so it may not do what you want.

```
"2") echo "please enter an number to view universities or a state name to view the number of uni in that state"

read uni
if [ uni -le `cat Aus-Uni.txt | wc -l` ]
then
    echo `tail -$uni Aus-Uni.txt`
else
   echo "The number you entered is too large"
fi

#   This line had elif but there's no if for it to be an else for
if [`grep $uni Aus-Uni.txt | wc -l` -ne 0 ]
then
    echo `grep $uni Aus-Uni.txt`
else
    echo "No university in $uni was found"
fi
;;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `elif` doesn't have a matching `if`. The only *if* which you are using is terminated by the *fi* already.

If it's just for the syntax, replace `elif` by `if`. Of course whether or not the program is then actually doing what you want, I can't say.